# Color grading/matching strips in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Imagine you have a number of strips in the VSE and you want the white balance, the exposure, or the color balance to match between each strip. Would there be a setup that would enable you to display for example strip 1 (with strip modifiers if any)  in a window and strip 2 in another window? If such setup was possible, one would them add strip modifiers to strip 2 to match strip 1 (eyeballing).

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. You could stack the strips above each other and make a new preview window for each strip. At the bottom of the preview window is a channel number, simply set this for the strip you want to see.

   [image: Example Screenshot 1]
2. Or you can make 2 preview windows and turn on the Ghost offset function in the preview window. Simply turn on the ghost button and enter the frame offset so the black line lands on the shot you want to compare. Then toggle down the *Overlay* menu next to the offset and select "reference". The other preview window should show "Current", this will display whatever the green play indicator is stopped on.

   [image: Example Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Just use two **Transform** *Effect Strip*s for temporary side-by-side display and do your Color Balancing on top of these. Afterwards you can select your untransformed Strips and **Copy** your Modifiers **to Selected Strips**.

Your *Effect Strip*s **Blend Type** has be set to **OverDrop** *(or AlphaOver)* and you need to Scale and translate it accordingly (I uniform scaled both to around 0.55 of their size and translated their position into the corners).
Then you can apply a Color Balance Strip Modifier to them... To not get confused with or have unwanted side-effects from the underlying strips you might mute the source strips of your Transform strips.

[image: Beispiel]

You have to copy your Strips to be at the same Frame on different Channels as you cannot simultaneously show two different frames in Blender.

Comment: Can't follow the answer very well, could you rearrange your answer that is easiler for a beginner to understand ... like where are the buttons I need to click on to even begin to do that?

Comment: There are great [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) out there to get you started. Follow them first and you should be good to go ;-)